# How to check if i'm able to get to a remote server on a particular port

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, port, ping

i am on a Windows machine and need to connect to an application on a Unix box under a certain port.

i've been told it's open but i'm still having difficulties getting in, is there anything in can do on my end to debug this? how can i check if the port of the Unix server is really open from my IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Telnet.

E.g. `telnet example.com 80` to check if the server at example.com accepts connections on port 80.